# How to create multiple buttons and action programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3

I am using Swift 3.0. I am trying to generate dynamical grid of button how can I programmatically give each generated button a unique identifier

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
@IBOutlet weak var attendanceView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var xvalue = 8;
    var yvalue = 17;
    var button = UIButton();

    for _ in 0..<5{
        for _ in 0..<5{
        button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: xvalue, y: yvalue, width: 50 , height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = .red()
        button.addTarget(attendanceView, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.attendanceView.addSubview(button)
        xvalue = xvalue + 72;
        }
        xvalue=8;
        yvalue = yvalue + 60;
    }
}

func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green()
}
```

I got this far but it crashes when button is clicked.

Comment: Please, when you post a question about a crash, you must include the complete and exact error message from the crash and point out the exact line of code causing the crash.

Comment: Change _ to i, then add button.tag = i. But what has your title got to do with you saying there's a crash? What's the actual question here?

Answer (score 0):

Use `button.tag` to distinct the buttons. `red` is the property of `UIColor` so you access it `UIColor.red`. So adjust your for loop to that

```
for i in 0..<5 {
    for i in 0..<5 {
        button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: xvalue, y: yvalue, width: 50 , height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.addTarget(attendanceView, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.tag = i
        self.attendanceView.addSubview(button)         
    }
}
```

and in `buttonAction()` use `.tag`:

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    switch (sender.tag){
    case 0:
        //button 0 action
    case 1:
        //button 1 action
    case 2:
        //button 2 action
    case 3:
        //button 3 action
    case 4:
        //button 4 action
    default:
        //default
    }
}
```

Comment: What does any of this have to do with the unknown crash? And what is `i`?

Comment: OP' code not even compiling, what crash is unknown? `i` is id of a button i guess

Comment: Read the last line of the question (below the code).

Comment: if this code is compiling that means it is not Swift 3 actually

Answer (score 0):

My two cents: I think using so mocha buttons will conflict with different sizes and devices. better to use a collection.
Anyway using tag attribute is the correct way. awn using some sort of formula is good, for example:

```
for r in 0..<10 {
    for c in 0..<20 {
        let tag = 1 + (r * 30) + c
    }
}
```

In this way, you should have different no-overlapping tags.

In call back:

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    let tag = sender.tag
    let row = tag % 30 // modulus...
    let col = tag - row * 30...
}
```

or similar.